# DynamoDB Adjacency List Pattern

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, adjacency-list

I'm trying to better understand using the adjacency list pattern for many to many (m:n) relationship design in AWS DynamoDB.

Looking at the AWS docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html we have an example with an Invoice and Bill entity with an m:n relationship.

[image]

I understand that I can get details of all bills associated with a particular invoice by reading a single partition. For example I can query for Invoice-92551 and know some attributes of the 2 bills that are associated with it based on the additional items in the partition.

My question is what do I have to do to get the full bill attributes for these 2 bills. Does this require 2 additional queries using the IDs I derived from the invoice partition, or is there some other pattern I am missing here?

**Additional Details**
Referencing the 2 different descriptions of Bill items in the screenshot:

- Bill items in Invoice partitions: "Attributes of this bill in this invoice"
- Bill items in their own partitions: "More attributes of this bill"

Does this mean that my Invoice partitions should include any Bill attributes I want to access via minimal queries? I was originally thinking the Bill partitions would contain most of what I want, but that doesn't quite make sense if I want to get at them by Invoice.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: issue multiple queries or duplicate some bill data. When you query for an invoice and its bills, you'll get

- More attributes of this invoice, and
- Attributes of this bill *in this invoice.*

You will *not* get "More attributes of this bill" for any bills. To get those, you must query for the bills themselves. You can issue individual `GetItem` queries or a single `BatchGetItem` query with the bill IDs (limited to 100 bills per query).

Alternatively, you can duplicate some values from "More attributes of this bill" to each `invoice-bill` item to avoid the second query at the cost of storage and insert/update complexity.

Answer (score 0):

No, no additional queries - unless you ask ("project") only certain attributes, your query will retrieve all the attributes of the bills together with its key.

DynamoDB stores each partition together on a single node, so it's efficient to fetch the entire partition. This partition is defined by its "partition key" (your invoice number). The partition contains a bunch of "items" (your bills), each item has its own "sort key" (your bill ID) and any number of "attributes". When DynamoDB reads the partition, it reads those items in order, with all their attributes, and can return all of them unless you specifically asked it not to. Note that even if you ask it only to return a subset (a "projection") of these attributes, Amazon still needs to read them from disk, and you will still pay for this I/O.

Comment: So this works if all attributes I need are available in the order items in the invoice partitions correct? The AWS docs make it look like the orders have their own partitions with their specific attributes while the ones in the invoice partitions would only have attributes related to the invoice. I'm assuming this means I'd have to copy all attributes in both places?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand Amazon's example. Only individual "Items" with a specific sort key, not "Partitions", have additional attributes. The Example above also mentions they use GSI. GSI (global secondary index) allows you to copy all the same attributes to items indexed by a different key. Maybe this GSI is what means you won't need to "copy all attributes in both places" - this is exactly what GSI does for you.

Comment: I think what I am understanding though is that there is no magic way to include data from other partitions in a single partition read. A GSI effectively repartitions things from a read perspective, but if I'm starting with an Invoice id and get associated bills, I would only have access to whatever attributes are in that partition and then have to re-issue queries for data in other partitions? Alternatively, I could include more attributes in my InvoiceBill items to access them on the first read.

Comment: I have the same question. It makes me wonder what’s the advantage to choose adjacency list pattern compared to having different tables for the Bills. It requires additional queries anyway.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. When querying for an `invoice`, you will not get attributes from the `bill` items—only the `invoice-bill` items.